# How do I temporarily run a tick function (Minecraft data packs)

Tags: minecraft

I am making a parkour map where you run over water to temporarily summon ice beneath your feet, however I don't now how to temporarily run a tick function.

Comment: Please read [ask].  You need to put some level of effort into your question.  Explain the problem thoroughly, and show us what you've already tried, why it didn't work, and what you've researched.  Also, I'm no expert on Minecraft datapacks, but I'm pretty sure you can't "conditionally" run a function.  That's not really how functions are supposed to work.  You just make the function do nothing whenever you don't need it to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. When the player goes to run across the desired area, give them frost walker boots. Have them either step on a pressure plate, or open a door or something next to an observer that is linked to a command block that uses the command `/gamerule randomTickSpeed <desired tick speed>`. (Remove the <>.) I don't know what you want the tick speed to be, but I do warn you that high values might cause lag. Do some experimenting of your own by simply using the command above while looking at some wheat. The higher the tick speed, the faster it grows. After the player has run across the area, the ice should be gone in an instant.